# Spring Tool Suite missing Spring MVC project template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In many examples/tutorials about creating web services using Spring MVC framework are using Spring MVC project template. I can't find it in my project templates list. Am I missing some plugin installed?

Comment: I have the same problem with version STS 3.6.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The templates should be available via a link on the dashboard as shown in the screenshot below. There is no plugin required.

[image: STS dashboard]

The available templates should be as below:

[image]

Comment: In version STS 3.6.1.RELEASE, the dashboard contain no such `Spring Template Project`

Answer (score 14):

for version: 3.7.1

1) Go to File->New

2) Click on Spring Legacy Project

3) Scroll down and select Spring MVC

Answer (score 5):

In New Spring Project form click on "Configure Templates..."
Then in Preference->Spring->Dashboard check Use Old Dashboad
It will be appear

Answer (score 3):

Try this , it solved my issue.

1. Go to New Project -> Spring Legacy Project. For first use, only show "Simple Project" folder.
2. Select Configure templates.. (blue link).
3. In Template Projects window, delete "spring-data-gemfire" and "spring-integration", and check "Show self-hosted templates ..." (at bottom), and then press Apply -> OK
4. Just wait while refreshing process, and "Spring MVC Project" should be showed.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to File -> *New*
- Select *Spring Legacy Project*
- Look for **Spring MVC Project** under *Templates* (Last one in the list, Scroll down if needed)

If you don't see the *Spring MVC Project*, Select [Configure templates..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlXwK.png) link

[image]

- Under *Preference* -> *Spring* -> *Dashboard*
- Check **Use Old Dashboad** and press *Apply* - *Ok*.

[image]

> Wait while refreshing process....

- You should be able to see **Spring MVC Project** now.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem when i started using sts 3.6.1 version on my laptop. at meanwhile when i choosen spring  legacy project folder no spring mvc project folder shown up.but i cofigured my  firewall proxy setting and easily got that folder so soon. so before going for mvc first you check urs firewall and proxies.

steps to configure proxies from native to manual to shown spring mvc project:-
window--->preferences--->network connection-->active provider-->choose manual-->ok then go and check spring legacy folder spring mvc will appear