# SpringSource Tool Suite missing Spring MVC project template

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin

This is not a duplicate of [Spring Tool Suite missing Spring MVC project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533123/spring-tool-suite-missing-spring-mvc-project-template)

Using STS 2.9.2 and have the com.springsource.sts.wizard_2.9.2.201205071000-RELEASE in my plugins folder.

I want to use Spring MVC project template but cannot find it either on dashboard or under the "New->Other->SpringSource Tool Suite" menu.

I do not want to make a new installation, lots of installed plugins exist.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For STS 3.0, the way that template projects are accessed has been changed, so it doesn't surprise me that you don't see the template project in the dashboard.  However, you should see it in the new dialog.  I'm not sure what could be happening.  You could have a look at your error log and look for relevant stack traces (and paste them here).

Or you could install STS 3.1 or later.  The easiest is probably to just go to the git repo where the template project exists, clone it and import it into your workspace as a maven project.

Here's the repo:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase

The only difference between doing that and using a true template project is that the template project configures a few things automatically for you, like the base package and the project name.  All this can be changed after importing, however.

Comment: Go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Error log

Answer (score 6):

In STS v3.3.0, select File > New > Spring project - when you get there, you will see bunch of options under "Templates" section. One of them is Spring MVC Project. Select that and follow the directions.

Comment: The list of templates isn't showing. It says requires downloading instead!!

Comment: I can see this is STS 3.6.1 as well. No downloads needed. Check your setup again.

Answer (score 0):

As user @AndrewEisenberg suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303914/248616), viewing the Error Log gives me the errors as below

- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started
- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-gemfire-sts-templates/master/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started

So having a close look at the error in Error Log, by `Windows - Show View - Other - Error Log`, after calling `File - New Project - Spring Project`, I see the cause for this symptom.

It causes by the internet connection which cannot reach https://raw.github.com

Answer (score 0):

i was able to see the option of Spring MVC Project Template here
[image]