# Spring project template not showing templates

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, templates, spring-mvc

I downloaded Spring STS 3.6.1 and I tried to create a spring MVC project, but the templates are missing:

[image]

As you can see it says requires downloading! I pressed Refresh several times and restarted STS, but I still can't get it to list the templates.

When I pressed configure templates:

[image]

I'm working on my home laptop running Windows 7. I'm able to access Eclipse market place and I'm not behind a proxy. I tried another laptop also running Windows 7, but in vain.

What is wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341643/cannot-find-spring-mvc-project-when-creating-new-web-application-project-using-s

Comment: refer this my recent answer.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35505605/4192735) http://stackoverflow.com/a/35505605/4192735

Answer (score 0):

As user @AndrewEisenberg suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303914/248616), viewing the Error Log gives me the errors as below

- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started
- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-gemfire-sts-templates/master/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started

So having a close look at the error in Error Log, by `Windows - Show View - Other - Error Log`, after calling `File - New Project - Spring Project`, I see the cause for this symptom.

It causes by the internet connection which cannot reach https://raw.github.com