# Cannot find Spring MVC project when creating new web application project using STS?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to Spring MVC and trying to learn from the internet tutorial such as these good ones from [journaldev](http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite), [springsource](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/77477-how-to-create-a-spring-3-mvc-project-with-sts), and [codejava](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide#CreateSpringMVCProject)

All of those tell me use [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts) as the IDE and to go for `New Project - Spring Template Project - Spring MVC Project`.

Though in my case, using the version 3.6.1.RELEASE of STS, I can NOT find any Spring MVC Project options there.

Do you have the same issue using STS?

p.s.

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533188/248616) for previous version of STS, though it not works for version 3.6.1.

Seeing no MVC template snapshot.

[image]

Comment: A similar questions posted a week ago ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207198/spring-project-template-not-showing-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user @AndrewEisenberg suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303914/248616), viewing the Error Log gives me the errors as below

- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-templates/master/si-sts-templates/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started
- Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-gemfire-sts-templates/master/builds/descriptor.xml failed on Connection to https://raw.github.com refused. Retry attempt 0 started

So having a close look at the error in Error Log, by `Windows - Show View - Other - Error Log`, after calling `File - New Project - Spring Project`, I see the cause for this symptom.

It causes by the internet connection which cannot reach https://raw.github.com

Comment: yes, the project templates are loaded dynamically from GitHub. If STS doesn't have a working network connection to GitHub, those project templates cannot be used directly. Maybe there is a proxy in place that needs to be configured? You can take a look at the network settings via the preferences in Eclipse/STS.

Comment: In addition to that you could also clone the GitHub repo for the Spring MVC Showcase project (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) manually and import that project as a Maven project into STS.

Comment: @MartinLippert Thanks for your GitHub cloning advice; though we can hardly create a Spring MVC project from this showcase.

Comment: @MartinLippert I've talked with the ISP and the issue is on their site. Vietnam incurs the cable fault issue recently and cause many consequences as what they say.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't sound like a defect in STS or anything we can do at the moment, right? Otherwise, let me know.

Answer (score 13):

I've just solved the problem. These are my way:
- Go to New Project -> Spring Project. For first use, only show "Simple Project" folder.
- Select Configure templates.. (blue link).
- In Template Projects window, delete "spring-data-gemfire" and "spring-integration", and check "Show self-hosted templates ..." (at bottom), and then press Apply -> OK
- Just wait while refreshing process, and "Spring MVC Project" should be showed.

Comment: At first it didn't work for me, but after a restart it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Step:1-Go to File->New

Step:2-Click on Spring Legacy Project

Step:3-see a Templates Box, scroll it down you will find Spring Mvc Project

Answer (score 3):

Firstly File -> New Project -> Spring -> Spring Legacy project & finally select what you want. also refer attached images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`New Project -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project`

Comment: There is no such menu for 3.1.6 version of STS

Comment: In your question you mentioned you are using 3.6.1.RELEASE. Are you on 3.6.1.RELEASE or 3.1.6 version. I used 3.6.0 and 3.6.2. I see this option. I don't think this option is just removed in 3.6.1.RELEASE

Comment: Yeah you are right. We have that menu. Mine is 3.6.1and 3.6.2

Comment: I find the cause - the ISP has something wrong in their routing.

Answer (score 0):

File->New-->Spring Legacy Project----> scroll down to Spring Mvc Project

Comment: Try to elaborate your answer.