# Cannot find Spring MVC Template Project in STS 3.7.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a problem with Spring Tool Suite 3.7.2.

When I navigate to create a new project, "New-->Spring Legacy Project" does not contain any template options.

I have tried configure to templates, but it didn't help me.
I'm looking for an empty Spring MVC Template Project, not a showcase.

Comment: No existing Spring MVC template. Try to create Spring Framework application first: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ . First step, I suggest 4 ways to inialitize a Spring MVC project: 1. Maven project, 2. Gradle project. 3. Spring boot project. 4. Check out `git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content.git` then modify source code.

Comment: @ĐỗNhưVý no, i need the Spring MVC Project. My problem is that "Templates" box doesn't refreshing.

Comment: @ĐỗNhưVý [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341643/cannot-find-spring-mvc-project-when-creating-new-web-application-project-using-s?rq=1) didn't help me, but I need it

Comment: In the current version of Spring Tool Suite (3.7.3.RELEASE), I just check my `Spring Tool Suite` IDE. Oh, in **legacy project** has Spring MVC template. But I don't recommend do this way, because it is **legacy**.

Comment: The dialog has to access the network in order to get the templates from a remote server. Maybe that network access is blocked and otherwise problematic in your setting. I would recommend to grab an existing example from somewhere and import the project as existing Maven project into STS (manually via the "Import Existing Maven Project" action).

Answer (score 1):

In spring legacy project (File->New->Spring Legacy Project) click 'Configure templates', and remove 'spring-data-gemfire' and 'spring-integration'
and then click Ok!
if not working also check 'Show self-hosted templates in new Template wizard'